# Error generating CRD: `DeepCopy of "interface{}" is unsupported`

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I want to define a CRD struct and generate Custom resource that has a field that can take up any value.

If the struct was to be something like:

```
type MyStruct struct{
    MyField interface{} `json:"myfield"`
}
```

I would like `MyField` to store a number or a string in the CRD:

```
myfield:2
```

or

```
myfield:"somestring"
```

However I get an error:

```
DeepCopy of "interface{}" is unsupported. Instead, use named interfaces with DeepCopy<named-interface> as one of the methods.
```

How do I work around this problem?

Comment: Seems like a strange thing to do, you could also just have `myfield` be a string and check if its a number on runtime.